# Jgit clone specific tag

Tags: java, clone, jgit

I am using jgit library to clone code. I am able to do that, but I wanted to know whether I can clone specific TAG. I found out that I can clone specific branch by

```
"Git.cloneRepository().setURI(remotePath).setBranch("BranchName").setDirectory(new File(localPath)).call();"
```

But my need is to clone Specific Tag. Thanks in advance for any help or suggestion..... I have given below the code I am using

```
public String checkOutCode(String remotePath) throws IOException {
        String localPath = Constants.CODEBASE;;
        Repository localRepo;
        Git git;
        LOGGER.info("Code Checkout Started");

        localRepo = new FileRepository(localPath + "/.git");
        CustomConfigSessionFactory cuFactory = new CustomConfigSessionFactory();

        SshSessionFactory.setInstance(cuFactory);        
        git = Git.cloneRepository().setURI(remotePath).setDirectory(new File(localPath)).call();

        LOGGER.info("Code Checked out at " + localRepo + " " + git.toString());

        return localPath;
    }
```

Comment: The `CloneCommand` fetches all tags. Have you checked whether the desired tag is present in the cloned repository?

Comment: yes, the desired tag is present in the repository I cloned. I think I will switch it to the desired tag...

Comment: Then this question can be closed or deleted, right?

Comment: Yes, this question can be closed. Thank you